# Can't locate Math/Random/ISAAC.pm in @INC

Tags: bugzilla

This is a version of bugzilla that has been upgraded to a new shared hosting server (still running Linux.) See bottom of post for full error message.

```
./checksetup.pl does not complain of any missing modules and completes successfully
```

There are a number of local perl modules located in `~/perl5/lib/perl5` including the module reported as missing below.

`perl -V` reports the following environment variable value (NB have replaced root of home folder in this output with `~`)

```
 %ENV:
    PERL5LIB="/~/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi:/~/perl5/lib/perl5:/~/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi:/~/perl5/lib/perl5"
    PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/~/perl5"
  @INC:
    /~/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /~/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /~/perl5/lib/perl5
    /~/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /~/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /~/perl5/lib/perl5
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Does Bugzilla ignore the PERL5LIB environment variable?

```
Full error message is:
Can't locate Math/Random/ISAAC.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . lib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at Bugzilla/RNG.pm line 28.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/RNG.pm line 28.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Util.pm line 50.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Util.pm line 50.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Error.pm line 33.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Error.pm line 33.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Install/Filesystem.pm line 31.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Install/Filesystem.pm line 31.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 38.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla.pm line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla.pm line 38.
Compilation failed in require at index.cgi line 34.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at index.cgi line 34.
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Windows, but you can adapt it for Linux too.

---

**Math::Random::ISAAC** 
**1. Download** [Math-Random-ISAAC-1.004.tar.gz](http://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/J/JA/JAWNSY/Math-Random-ISAAC-1.004.tar.gz)
**2. On a console open the "cpan" console**.
**3. Go to the path of the file downloaded**

> C:>cd C:\strawberry\cpan
>   C:\strawberry\cpan>cd Math-Random-ISAAC-1.004

**4. perl Makefile.PL**

> C:\strawberry\cpan\Math-Random-ISAAC-1.004>perl Makefile.PL
>
> Writing Makefile for Math::Random::ISAAC  Writing MYMETA.yml and
>   MYMETA.json

**5. Dmake**

> C:\strawberry\cpan\Math-Random-ISAAC-1.004>dmake
>
> cp lib/Math/Random/ISAAC.pm blib\lib\Math\Random\ISAAC.pm     
>   cp lib/Math/Random/ISAAC/PP.pm blib\lib\Math\Random\ISAAC\PP.pm

**6. dmake test**

> C:\strawberry\cpan\Math-Random-ISAAC-1.004>dmake test 
>     C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e"
>   "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t  t/01compile.t
>   .............. ok 
>     t/02sequence.t ............. ok 
>     t/03memory.t
>   ............... skipped: Test::LeakTrace required to test memory leaks
>     t/04uniform.t .............. skipped: Author tests not required for
>   installation 
>  t/05fallback.t ............. skipped:
>   Test::Without::Module and Math::Random::ISAAC::XS required to test
>   fallback ability 
>  t/06exceptions.t ........... ok
>     t/release-dist-manifest.t .. skipped: these tests are for release
>   candidate testing 
>     t/release-kwalitee.t ....... skipped: these tests
>   are for release candidate testing 
>     t/release-pod-coverage.t ...
>   skipped: these tests are for release candidate testing
>     
> t/release-pod-syntax.t ..... skipped: these tests are for release
>   candidate testing     
> t/release-portability.t .... skipped: these tests
>   are for release candidate testing     All tests successful. 
>   Files=11,
>   Tests=607, 15 wallclock secs ( 0.17 usr +  0.14 sys =  0.31 CPU)
>     Result: PASS

**7. dmake install**

> C:\strawberry\cpan\Math-Random-ISAAC-1.004>dmake install  Installing
>   C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\Math\Random\ISAAC.pm  Installing
>   C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\Math\Random\ISAAC\PP.pm   Appending
>   installation info to C:\strawberry\perl\lib/perllocal.pod

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is that you run `./checksetup.pl` as your own user while when you run Bugzilla in the web server that's probably the user www-data. If that's the case, you need to configure your web server to see `~/perl5/lib/perl5`.

Adding the following (after replacing foobar) to the Apache configuration - if that's what you use - will probably work:

```
SETENV PERL5LIB /home/foobar/perl5/local/lib/perl5:/home/foobar/perl5/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Two related articles that might help: (published by myself)

- [Can't locate ... in @INC](http://perlmaven.com/cant-locate-in-inc)
- [How to change @INC to find Perl modules in non-standard locations](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations)

Answer (score 0):

on command line on windows

```
cd c:\perl64\bin
ppm install Math-Random-ISAAC
```